# PowerShell Stopping and Starting Windows Services on Remote Computer

Tags: powershell

I have a very basic PowerShell that accepts a list of Windows Server and Services on them and then stops the Services

```
Get-Service -ComputerName machine1 -Name service1 -ErrorAction Stop | Stop-Service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Although I had explicitly mentioned -ErrorAction as Stop, in a case if one of the Server is not reachable, the Powershell doesn't come back. How do I change this behaviour at least in a way to stop processing after a certain amount of time as "n" secs which again can be passed thru parameter?

Comment: Simplest would be to enclose it in a `Test-Connection` like this `if (Test-Connection machine1 -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { ... }`

Comment: Wonderful, I just thought of making it a little easier by wrapping the script like this `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName machine1 -Quiet)  {all my current code}` Thanks a ton for your suggestion of Test-Connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Incorporating both comments, we end up with following</sub>

Enclose the current script in a `Test-Connection` that allows you to first verify if a computer is actually reachable:

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName machine1 -Quiet) 
{
    all your current code
}
```